# Why do the clouds near the horizon appear two dimensional?

Tags: refraction, geophysics

Look at the photo. The clouds right above us seem real, but those near the horizon appear as if they are from a painting.

[image: clouds]

They lack depth and are visually flat. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because of two reasons: relative distance and angular size. If we see cumulus clouds near overhead (stratus clouds would be a separate argument due to height and shape), they're relatively near and apparently 3D. But on the horizon in any direction, much further away and generally speaking smaller angular size (same exact cloud near overhead would have a much larger angular size). It's fairly easy to visualize in 3D with practice. The reason I say "near overhead" and not overhead is because we'd be looking at the bottom of a cloud and typically for cumulus, they're taller than wider. So that could also contribute to the perceived difference.